# Finding the integral $\int\frac1{\sqrt t(1+t)}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac1{\sqrt t(1+t)}dt$$
I've been trying to evaluate the integral for the above equation but just keep on hitting dead ends. How do I approach this one?

Comment: Please copy the integral with proper formatting rather than posting a link to an image. Also: are you sure you want to do this via integration by parts?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to do the formatting thing. As for integration by parts. I'm not too sure how to approach the question. I've been stuck on it for ages.

Comment: What happens with the $u$-substitution $u=\sqrt{t}$?

Comment: @user411697 Someone did it for you; but for future questions it's worth reading up on the formatting possibilities/guidelines on this site.

Comment: Here's a starting point to learn how to format the formulas: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by using the substitution $u = \root \of t$, $du = \frac{1}{2\root \of t} dt$, you end up with 
$$2\int \frac{1}{1+u^2}du$$

We then preform another substitution $u = \tan x$, $du = \sec^2 x dx$ resulting in 
$$2\int \frac{\sec^2 x}{\sec^2x} dx = 2x  + C= 2 \tan^{-1}u + C= 2\arctan \root \of t + C$$

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest using a substitution rather than integration by parts.

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}\left( 1+t \right)} \, \mbox{d}t$$

Now let $u=\sqrt{t}$ so $t=u^2$ and $t'(u) = 2u$, then:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}\left( 1+t \right)} \, \mbox{d}t \to \int \frac{1}{u\left( 1+u^2 \right)}  t'(u) \, {\mbox{d}u} = 2\int \frac{1}{1+u^2 }  \, {\mbox{d}u} $$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I got it from there. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user411697 Alright, you're welcome. I'll edit your title as you don't need integration by parts here...

Answer (score 0):

Subsitute $u=\sqrt{t}$ and integrate wrt to $u$. Use partial fractions to seperate the two factors in the denominator.

Comment: There's no need for partial fractions after the substitution.

Comment: I think you mean $\color{red}{u}(1+u^2)$ and that factor $u$ "disappears" with the substitution, since $t'(u) = 2u$; see my answer.

Comment: @StackTD Yeah. Just realised that. my mistake : )

Comment: Alright, no problem!